# While loop wont end on multiple conditions

Tags: c, while-loop

So basically the while loop should end if the number 2 or number 4 is inputted in the menu. However, the loop does not end and it keeps redisplaying the main menu. If I use the statements separate one by one it works but if I join them into one condition this happens...

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int answer;
    int menunum;

    answer = 0;
    menunum = 0;


        while(menunum !=4 || menunum != 2)
        {
            printf("Wellcome to my game in order to start pick the first option to set the number of questions you want to be asked \n");
            printf("1. Enter the amount of questions you want to be asked \n");
            printf("2. Start Quiz \n");
            printf("3. Display the number of correct and incorrect answers \n");
            printf("4. Exit the game \n");
            scanf("%d", &menunum);
        }

        printf("END OF PROGRAM\n");
        scanf("%d", &answer);
}
```

Comment: while(menunum !=4 && menunum != 2)

Comment: Your || should be &&

Comment: Change `while(menunum !=4 || menunum != 2)` to `while(menunum !=4 && menunum != 2)`

Comment: `menunum != 4 || menunum != 2` is true for *every* value of `menunum`. Think about it...

Comment: OK - this is a boolean logic error.  Who close-voted it as 'Primarily opinion-based'?  :)

Answer (score 2):

> So basically the while loop should end if the number 2 or number 4 is
>   inputted in the menu.

So just write in C what you have said.

while( !( menunum == 4 || menunum == 2 ) )

or (if to include `<iso646.h>`)

```
while( not ( menunum == 4 or menunum == 2 ) )
```

that is equivalent to

```
while( menunum != 4 && menunum != 2 )
```

Comment: This is an application of DeMorgan's Law, https://brilliant.org/wiki/de-morgans-laws .  It's a nifty little trick that can help make conditions easier to read without mangling them.